# What is the intended way to identify a shop in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I want to store some additional data for each shop in my backend. My first thought was to use the numerical shop ID for identifying the shop. But the ID is rarely used or provided by Shopify. Example: The webhook events contain only the shop domain as metadata, not the ID (for whatever reason). But my understanding is, that the domain for the shop can change, right? So it doesn't seem a good idea to use the domain as an ID in our backend.

But when using the shop ID, I now need to retrieve the shop ID using the domain + shop access token every time an event comes in.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The host, like `shop.myshopify.com`, is not the domain of your shop. It's a sort of internal domain. I think you're allowed to change it once, but not more than that (and there is no particular reason to do it).

Just use the domain, that's how normally you identify your shop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have a link to that restriction? I found something about changing a primary domain, but nothing about any restriction: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/domain-type/change-primary-domain
Is the primary domain the one I receive in the X-Shopify-Shop-Domain header?

Comment: @moen The primary domain is the domain you're using for your website: shop.com, you can change that anytime you want. On the other side shop.myshopify.com is the name of your shop and you cannot change it. X-Shopify-Shop-Domain will always be shop.myshopify.com Hope it's clear

Comment: Okay, so given this shop resource object: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/shop#resource-object The "domain" is the (primary) shop domain which can be changed, but the "myshopify_domain" is the internal one. And it's equal to the domain provided in X-Shopify-Shop-Domain and can not be changed. I think because the official examples provided different domains for the "domain" property, I thought it would change too. Didn't see the "myshopify_domain" property. In that case, I will go with the internal shopify domain. Thank you for your help!